# How to parse a File in power shell with conditional and garbage

Tags: parsing, powershell

I need to get part of  this file for example, I need extract the following

```
Main, Branches\Branch1
```

in one variable also the I cannot have duplicate values

It is possible with powershell?

This is the file:

```
This is a garbage line
This is another garbage line
c:\Folder\Main\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Main\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Branches\Branch1\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Branches\Branch1\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Branches\Branch1\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Main\Folder\..\Folder
c:\Folder\Main\Folder\..\Folder
this is the final line..
```

Answer (score 2):

But of course ...

According to the fact $files contain your lines

```
$files = Get-content "your file"
```

You can use the following to be sure that there is no duplicate :

```
$files | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Then you can use Test-path to be sure that path exists

```
$files | Sort-Object -Unique | where {Test-Path $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
```

Comment: Thanks man, when I put  $files | Sort-Object -Unique delete all the util information and just show this:This is a garbage line
This is another garbage line
this is the final line..

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Does it answer your question ?

Comment: No, I have probhlem with the first line

Comment: What is the problem with the garbage line ?

Answer (score -1):

This will extract those values from the sample data using a `-like` filter to take out the garbage and a `-replace` to do the extract.  The `sort -unique` will remove the duplicates, but it won't keep the extracted values in the same order they were in the file.

```
(get-content testfile.txt) -like 'c:\Folder*' -replace 'c:\\Folder\\(.+?)\\Folder.+','$1' |
 sort -unique
```